# How to create a dynamic request variables in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a few values in CSV files. I need to pass this values in JSR223 sampler. if suppose, in CSV files it has 4 variables are present in first row then i need to write two line below.

Example 1 in JSR223 sampler :

```
('usr', '${Var1}', '${Var2}')
('usr', '${Var3}', '${Var4}')
```

If 6 variables are present in second row of CSV files, they my script should have three lines.

Example 2 in JSR223 sampler :

```
('usr', '${Var1}', '${Var2}')
('usr', '${Var3}', '${Var4}')
('usr', '${Var5}', '${Var6}')
```

My scenario here is, each row will have different count of values would be present. So, how can i create my JSR223 sampler request count based on the values counts that is present in CSV files. May i know how to create this scenario in JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
def lines = new File('test.csv').readLines()

lines.each { line ->
    log.info('Line from CSV: ' + line)
    def request = new StringBuilder()
    def values = line.split(',')
    def counter = 0
    1.upto(values.size() / 2, { it ->
        request.append("('usr',").append(values[counter]).append(", '").append(values[counter + 1]).append(" ')")
        if (it != values.size() / 2) {
            request.append(System.getProperty('line.separator'))
        }
        counter = counter + 2
    })
    log.info('Generated request: ' + System.getProperty('line.separator') + request.toString())
}
```

should do the trick for you.

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Reading a File in Groovy](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-file-read)
- [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri. I will try this step and confirm you back.